# How do you hide an image on a Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a Python project for school, and am using the Tkinter canvas object as the main interface, because of the visuals. I desperately need a way to hide an object on the canvas, and am not sure how.

I know this is probably a dumb question, but I really need an answer.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: What do you mean? I want a way to hide any TKinter Canvas object I want using a function or whatnot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a canvas object, you can use `canvas.itemconfig(item, state='hidden')` where `item` is the item ID returned by `canvas.create_xxxx(...)`.

To show the hidden item, use `canvas.itemconfig(item, state='normal')`.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful